# Pyspark when statement

Tags: pyspark

Hi I'm starting to use Pyspark and want to put a when and otherwise condition in:

```
df_1 = df.withColumn("test", when(df.first_name == df2.firstname & df.last_namne == df2.lastname, "1. Match on First and Last Name").otherwise ("No Match"))
```

I get the below error and wanted some assistance to understand why the above is not working.

Both df.first_name and df.last_name are strings  and also df2.firstname and df2.lastname strings too

Error:
ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: enclose the equality checks in brackets -- `(a==b) & (c==d)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your statement:

- For `df.withColum()`, you can not use df and df2 columns in one statement. First join the two dataframes using `df.join(df2, on="some_key", how="left/right/full")`.
- Enclose the **and** condition of "when" clause in round brackets: `(df.first_name == df2.firstname) & (df.last_name == df2.lastname)`
- The string literals of "when" and "otherwise" should be enclosed in `lit()` like: `lit("1. Match on First and Last Name")` and `lit("No Match")`.
- There is possibly a typo in your field name `df.last_namne`.

Comment: Thank you Azhar - I am still getting use to PySpark and syntax but this has helped greatly.